# Swift 4 KVC - Cast to unrelated type always fail

Tags: swift4

I am not able to conditional cast `KeyPath` related object to `KeyPath` with its superclass. Have this easy setup

```
class Foo {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
class Bar: Foo {}

let keyPath = \Bar.name
if let keyPath = keyPath as? KeyPath<Foo, String> {
    print(keyPath)
}
```

It's giving me warning that my print method will never be executed because

> Cast from 'KeyPath<Bar, String>' to unrelated type 'KeyPath<Foo,
>   String>' always fails

Generally speaking I want to be able to operate with `AnyObject` inside `KeyPath` but this behaviour is preventing me from doing that. Can someone explain how downcasting works for `KeyPath` and perhaps offer a way around?

Comment: Well, the types are unrelated. You cannot cast one generic to another generic. Generic types are not subclassing each other. Why do you need that cast? Why do you even need key paths in Swift? They are made to work with Obj-C, not with pure Swift.

Comment: It's a mixed project, we are using KVC mainly for manipulation with NSManagedObject subclasses.